# Getting UTC time for any time and handling daylight saving as well

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdateformatter, ios9.3

I have written a function to get UTC time string corresponding to any time string passed as an argument to function.

```
+(NSString *)getUTCTime:(NSString *)selectedTime
{
    NSString *strFormat;
    if ([self is24HourFormat:selectedTime]){
        strFormat = @"HH:mm";
    }
    else{
        strFormat = @"hh:mm a";
    }
    NSLocale *baseLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterlocal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatterlocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    dateFormatterlocal.locale = baseLocale;
    [dateFormatterlocal setDateFormat:strFormat];

    NSDate *selectedDate = [dateFormatterlocal dateFromString:selectedTime];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterUTC = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatterUTC setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    dateFormatterUTC.locale = baseLocale;
    [dateFormatterUTC setDateFormat:strFormat];


    NSString *utcTimeString = [dateFormatterUTC stringFromDate:selectedDate];
    return utcTimeString;
}
```

It working fine for Mumbai, India time zone. But if i change the timezone to London, its returning me the same time that I'm passing in function argument. Currently it is UTC+1 in London. Does `NSDateFormatter` handle daylight saving?

Comment: what is the need exactly? do you want time in utc format ?

Comment: I need to send UTC time corresponding to selected time by user to server.

Comment: By definition, UTC has no time zone.  I think you meant GMT+1.

Comment: and from where user will select the time ?

Comment: From time picker user is selecting the time. He can be in any time zone. I have to send the UTC time corresponding to selected time to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **NSTimeZone** methods as shown below for daylight saving: See [NSTimeZone Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimeZone/nextDaylightSavingTimeTransitionAfterDate:)

1. **isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:**// will tell you if day light saving exist for this date
2. **daylightSavingTimeOffset** // will tell you how much offset is the time for daylight saving

Use below code it returns properly day light saving with offset

```
var timeZone:NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone(name:"Europe/London")!
print(timeZone.daylightSavingTime) //this will return true if day light saving present
print(timeZone.daylightSavingTimeOffset/(60*60))//this will give you number of hours by which the day light saving offset should be
print("timezone: \(timeZone)")//will give you detail about timezone
```

Comment: For London timezone its returning 0.000 offset. But right now it is UTC+1 in london.

Comment: @VarunMehta I have updated the **comment** and tested in on playground it works fine and gives me 1 offset for Europe/London. check above code and all the best.